# TeamCity HTTP Request in the context of Kotlin DSL

Tags: kotlin, bitbucket, teamcity, dsl, continuous-deployment

Is it possible to do an HTTP GET request inside the settings.kts file used to implement your TeamCity configuration with Kotlin?

If it is possible, how can it be achieved?

If it is not, what are the reasons?

Thanks

Comment: the question is not clear. What do you want to do?

Comment: I would like to query an external bitbucket server API so TeamCity can create projects based on the api results , hope it is clearer

Comment: You should be able to to this, you can at least open files under .teamcity and are allowed to use external libs. I am trying to populate a dropdown with tags from a docker repo. Ill report back if it works :)

Answer (score -3):

you can create the projects using [TeamCity REST API](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/REST+API)

Create a new build configuration with all settings: 
`POST http://teamcity:8111/app/rest/buildTypes`. The XML/JSON posted is the same as retrieved by GET request. (Note that /app/rest/project/XXX/buildTypes still uses the previous version notation and accepts another entity.)

Create a new empty build configuration:

```
POST plain text (name) to http://teamcity:8111/app/rest/projects/<projectLocator>/buildTypes
```

also, you able to create the projects using Kotlin DSL, but should use UI for acheave it.

```
package _Self.buildTypes

import jetbrains.buildServer.configs.kotlin.v2018_2.*
import jetbrains.buildServer.configs.kotlin.v2018_2.buildSteps.script

object Example : BuildType({
    name = "example"
steps {
    script {
        scriptContent = "ls -al"
    }
}
})
```